# How to remove radio button in spinner only in layout view android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have strange problem with spinner.
My spinner display radio button when i don't use it, check this out:

[Image 1 Radio when not use](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/2FNEcm150ROYwkW8ZEuOWo5GJYlkFXQ7MNKY2S8ecPi2sKHkSSdsEY8ah58LnDGBIKzy_xR7zjI=w1342-h458)

[Image 1 Radio when use spinner](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/Zr3_N2n5gDDCL0iC4zRCLgMKzVmOLLs3XNQ7Z-oQ9ibnF6o7zJJ-8mR3SUtsMipJnvBftTDLhCE=w1342-h458)

Someone know how fix it? I want radio button when i click on spinner and dropdown list shows, but now when i dont use spinner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can set view for spinner shown item and hidden item.

Comment: You must show a Dialog with `.setSingleChoiceItems()` when user clicks spinner, so you can't change the layout of an spinner's element when it is used or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you set adapter for your spinner you can set it's layout like this:

```
String[] arr = new String[]{"a","b","c"};

    selectionSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(
            R.id.dr);
 ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arr);  
 spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 selectionSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000" >


    <Spinner android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/dr" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

result:

[image]

[image]